# "Error: permission_denied at /place: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data." in Cloud FireStore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]I know most probably this is a "Rules" issue and have tried multiple ways around it with no success...following are my rules.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true
    }
  }
}
```

This is the React Component where I am calling the data:

```
componentDidMount(){
  console.log('mounted');

  let database = firebase.database();
  var ref = database.ref('place')
  console.log(ref)
  ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

  function gotData(data){
    console.log(data);

  }
  function errData(err){
    console.log('Error');
    console.log(err);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is showing rules for Firestore, but the code is accessing Realtime Database.  They are completely different database systems with different rules systems and APIs that have nothing in common.  You will need to examine and update the rules for Realtime Database instead (or change your code to query Firestore).

I can tell your code is using RTDB because of the call to `firebase.database()`.  You will want to use `firebase.firestore()` instead, if you are actually trying to query Firestore.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for pointing out, I have been following multiple aritcles hence this result I guess..

Comment: I am querying firestone now :    let database = firebase.firestore();
    let places = database.collection("place");
    console.log("places", places);    But the log shows bizzare data and not my actual documents from the database....anyways I understand thats a different question, will post another question for that